# Импорт js скриптов в одном файле

Tags: javascript

здравсвтуйте, перейду сразу к примеру на своем сайте я запускаю один файл стилей, который запускает остольные таким образом

```
@import url("reset.css");
@import url("layout.css");
@import url("style.css");
@import url("hack.css");
```

можно ли так же запускать js скрипты? и не вредно ли такое =)?

Answer (score 1):

> можно ли так же запускать js скрипты?

Можно так:

```
document.write('<script src=script1.js></script>')
document.write('<script src=script2.js></script>')
document.write('<script src=script3.js></script>')
```

Удобно для разработке. А потом при билде в релизной конфигурации просто слить все эти скрипты в один файл (тот, который подключается непосредственно на странице) и минифицировать.

Answer (score 0):

Можно подгружать их аяксом, а потом фигачить eval'ом. Но это имеет некоторые особенности. И кажется какие-то проблемы под IE. Но работает. Я сам использовал нечто подобное однажды, но только потому, что не мог заранее определить список того, что нужно подключить. Если же список известен, то лучше каждый раз руками подключать нужные файлы в html.

Comment: вот например ссылка с контакта : ) 
http://vkontakte.ru/js/loader_nav6701_0.js

Comment: Можно и без ajax'а - просто создавать тег script.
Можно использовать тот же requirejs.
Но я вижу основную идею такого подключения как удобство отладки. Подключен один файл - в релизе он одним и остаётся, а в дебаге просто добавляет подключение других скриптов как они есть.